# How to git reset an old commit for the purposes of branching off another commit

Tags: git

So, midway through a PR I realized this would be a lot easier if I had branched off another commit (let's call this commit A) on a separate branch. In short, my current PR (call this commit B) is dependent on that commit (commit A).

Unfortunately, while working on commit B, I made one commit. Let's call this commit B0. How do I checkout to prior to me commiting commit B0 so that I have non-committed files that I can stash? IN short, I want to stash my changes from commit B0, branch off commit A, and stash pop my changes onto commit A1. How do I do this?

Can I also cherry pick?

Answer (score 0):

`git reset HEAD~` returns the branch pointer to the last but one commit preserving work tree so your files will appear modified in `git status`. From that point you can stash them and continue.

Answer (score 0):

So, from how I understand it, your history looks like this:

```
       your pull request
             ↓
A --- B0 --- B
```

And you actually want it to look like this:

```
A --- B0
 \
  \-- B
      ↑
updated pull request
```

In that case, you have multiple ways of doing so. A very quick way would be to just make a new branch off `A` and cherry-pick your commit:

```
git checkout -b new_pr A
git cherry-pick old_pr
```

Then you can push your new branch to your old branch to update the pull request. Or you check out your old branch and hard-reset it to the new branch.

You can also use interactive rebase to remove `B0` simply from the history (if that’s a good idea depends on whether you still want to use that for anything). For that, just run `git rebase -i A` and then in the editor remove the line for `B0`.